# AMP carousel pause/play

Tags: amp-html

I am working on a site that has to be ADA compliant and one of the things they require is for a slider/carousel to have a pause/play button. Is there a way to do this that will come up AMP valid?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [amp-carousel](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-carousel/) official docs, there is no mention of a feature to pause or play carousel.